# Create a new feature layer from an existing feature class selection with python/arcpy

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, feature-class

I am attempting to create a new layer from the selection of streams and rivers in an NHD feature class.  I have tried every iteration that I can think of without success.  I am very new to Python, so I am not sure I am even using the correct functions.

I have been reading help topics for SQL, MakeFeatureLayer, SelectByAttribute, CopyFeatures, SearchCursor, etc. for several days and cannot figure it out.

Things I need to do:

1. Create a new feature layer from a selection of "StreamRiver" in the table column "FType" from an NHD feature class.

Things you may need to know:

1. "huc4" is just a watershed shapefile that will not be manipulated.
2. The files are all stored locally.
3. The selection I need is called "StreamRiver" in the attribute table, but also has a value assigned (460) in the where clause in ArcGIS. (FType is equal to 460 - StreamRiver)
4. I am using Pycharm and ArcGIS Pro.
5. I have tried some other things in the Python window of ArcGIS, but this is most of the attempts.
6. I can't get the code example to contain the entire script.

```py
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\...\MyGDB.gdb"

Watershed = "huc4"

NHD = "NHDArea"

try:

    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


    #arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(NHD, "NHD_Rivers", [["FType", "=", "460"]])
    #arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(NHD, "NHD_Rivers", [["FType", "is equal to", "StreamRiver"]])
    #arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(NHD, "NHD_Rivers", [["FType", "is equal to", "460"]])
    #arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(NHD, "NHD_Rivers", [["FType", "=", "StreamRiver"]])
    #arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("NHDArea", "NHD_Rivers", [["FType", "=", "460"]])
    #arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("NHDArea", "NHD_Rivers", [["FType", "is equal to", "StreamRiver"]])
    #arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("NHDArea", "NHD_Rivers", [["FType", "is equal to", "460"]])
    #arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("NHDArea", "NHD_Rivers", [["FType", "=", "StreamRiver"]])
    #arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(NHD, "NHD_Rivers", ['"FType", = "StreamRiver"'])
    #Rivers = arcpy.SearchCursor(NHD, ['FType'], '"FType" = "StreamRiver"')
    #arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Rivers")


    #arcpy.PairwiseBuffer_analysis("NHD_Rivers", "River_Buffer", [["2", "Kilometers"]])

except:

    print("You made a mistake.")

    print(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

update:

I tried a new statement that did create a new feature layer, but it did not contain the parameters of the where_clause.

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(NHD, "NHD_Rivers", "'FType' = 'StreamRiver'")
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. The biggest mistake a new user can make is using `try` to early in the development process. You need your code to fail due to mistakes before you can successfully trap all errors. This is of particular importance in GIS SE, because you need to add a snippet of code with the error in order to get assistance.  This code block doesn't do anything (and should check in the checked-out Spatial Analyst), so it seems unlikely to generate an error.

Comment: Whenever you test/present code here I recommend removing any try/except statements which can mask otherwise useful error messages.

Comment: If it created a layer with no features, then it did in fact contain the `where_clause` parameter -- the string `'FType'` is never equivalent to the string `'StreamRiver'`. If you want a field value equal to a string you need to drop the apostrophe literals around the field name. Each data source has its own formatting rules -- shapefile requires quotes around the fieldname, which makes this an exercise in Python string formatting -- `"\"FType\" = 'StreamRiver'"` might work.